# Set JSP as Apache default page

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jboss

Hi,

I'm currently configuring a personal server for my very first time. I've Apache 2 and JBoss currently working, and they are both connected using mod_proxy.
Assuming my server IP is myserverip, I'm currently able to access any JSP file deployed in JBoss without typing the :8080. (http://myserverip:8080/myjsp --> http://myserverip/myjsp)

But now I want to configure my apache server to use a JSP page as it's default page, instead of index.html. For example, I want to access http://myserverip/myjsp as http://myserverip .
Assuming that myjsp is a .war that I have deployed in JBoss.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open your Apache configuration file httpd.conf
2. Find out line that read as follows: DirectoryIndex
3. Now set it as per your requirements: DirectoryIndex /myjsp/
4. Save and close the file.
5. Restart the Apache web server.

Comment: The httpd.conf. file is empty.

Comment: Then try adding the suggested line, or edit another config file (on my server there are like 5 of those)

Comment: you may want to try editing apache2.conf in that case.

Comment: The only references to the DirectoryIndex I've found are in the mods-enable/dir.conf and in the mods-available/dir.conf. In both of them I've the following line: DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
Is this the line that I have to change?

Comment: By the way, I'm working with Ubuntu, that's why my httpd.conf is empty.

Comment: I changed the DirectoryIndex in the mods-enabled to DirectoryIndex /myjsp/. Now when I type http://myserverip the browser shows the JBoss welcome page instead of the myjsp. Do you know how can I fix this?